# "pygame" is not accessed by Pylance

Tags: python, module

I am really new to Python, so explain everything like I'm 5 if you can. This has happened with multiple other modules, like when I tried to create a Discord bot but the module "wasn't accessed by pylance". I tried adding my folder with my modules in it to my extra paths in my settings.json file, and tried other modules like pyperclip, and nothing works. The only ones that work are built in ones like random and time. Aswell as that, when I run code with these modules, it shows this in the terminal:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Users\myname\OneDrive\Program7.py", line 423, in <module> import pygame ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'`

(in VSCode)

Comment: Try with pip3 install pygame

Comment: @Qualcuno2 already did that, after it's installed it still doesn't work

Comment: AI suggestions: Check if the module is installed: Open your terminal and type pip list. This will show you all the modules you have installed. If you don't see the module you're trying to use (like pygame), then you need to install it using pip install module_name.
Check your Python path: Python needs to know where to look for the installed modules. You can check your Python path by opening Python and typing import sys; print(sys.path). This will show you the list of directories Python is looking in for modules. If the directory where you installed the module is not in this list, you may need

Comment: to add it.
Use a virtual environment: Virtual environments are like separate toy boxes for each of your Python projects. They help keep your modules organized and prevent conflicts between different projects. You can create a virtual environment using a tool like venv or conda.
Restart your IDE: Sometimes, your code editor (like Visual Studio Code) doesn't recognize the newly installed modules until you restart it.

Comment: Try VSCode command (F1) "Python: Select Interpreter" to see if a different interpreter is selected.